# wso2 puppet agent gets error when try to install wso2am-2.1.0.zip after taking WUM updated files

Tags: wso2, puppet, wso2-api-manager

I was trying to take WUM updated wso2am-2.1.0.zip from puppet master to install to agent.

What i have tried:

1. Removed the existing wso2am-2.1.0.zip file from puppet master /etc/puppet/environments/production/modules/wso2am_runtime/files.
2. taken the updated wso2am-2.1.0.1497355516179.zip to /etc/puppet/environments/production/modules/wso2am_runtime/files and renamed it to wso2am-2.1.0.zip .
3. started the ./setup.sh on puppet agent.

I have got the below logs/error ....can some one please help me to fix this issue

```
[root@serverName opt]# ./setup.sh
#####################################################
                   Starting cleanup
#####################################################
kill 16255: No such process
#####################################################
               Setting up environment
#####################################################
#####################################################
 Installing
#####################################################
Info: Retrieving pluginfacts
Info: Retrieving plugin
Info: Loading facts
Info: Caching catalog for vlcapapigeebaas.fisdev.local
Info: Applying configuration version '1500030877'
Notice: /Stage[main]/Wso2am_runtime/Wso2base::Install/Wso2base::Ensure_directory_structures[/data/puppet-wso2-install-dir/packs]/Exec[create_directory_structure_/data/puppet-wso2-install-dir/wso2am-2.1.0//data/puppet-wso2-install-dir/packs]/returns: executed successfully
Notice: /Stage[main]/Wso2am_runtime/Wso2base::Install/Wso2base::Ensure_directory_structures[/data/puppet-wso2-install-dir]/Exec[create_directory_structure_/data/puppet-wso2-install-dir/wso2am-2.1.0//data/puppet-wso2-install-dir]/returns: executed successfully
Notice: /Stage[main]/Wso2am_runtime/Wso2base::Install/Wso2base::Clean_deployment[clean_on_pack_change]/File[/tmp/wso2am-2.1.0.zip]/ensure: defined content as '{md5}4751c6f550141e8caff12985dad93282'
Info: /Stage[main]/Wso2am_runtime/Wso2base::Install/Wso2base::Clean_deployment[clean_on_pack_change]/File[/tmp/wso2am-2.1.0.zip]: Scheduling refresh of Exec[check_diff]
Notice: /Stage[main]/Wso2am_runtime/Wso2base::Install/Wso2base::Clean_deployment[clean_on_pack_change]/Exec[check_diff]/returns: executed successfully
Info: /Stage[main]/Wso2am_runtime/Wso2base::Install/Wso2base::Clean_deployment[clean_on_pack_change]/Exec[check_diff]: Scheduling refresh of Exec[clean_temp_pack]
Notice: /Stage[main]/Wso2am_runtime/Wso2base::Install/Wso2base::Clean_deployment[clean_on_pack_change]/Exec[check_diff]: Triggered 'refresh' from 1 events
Info: /Stage[main]/Wso2am_runtime/Wso2base::Install/Wso2base::Clean_deployment[clean_on_pack_change]/Exec[check_diff]: Scheduling refresh of Exec[clean_temp_pack]
Notice: /Stage[main]/Wso2am_runtime/Wso2base::Install/Wso2base::Clean_deployment[clean_on_pack_change]/Exec[clean_temp_pack]/returns: executed successfully
Notice: /Stage[main]/Wso2am_runtime/Wso2base::Install/Wso2base::Clean_deployment[clean_on_pack_change]/Exec[clean_temp_pack]: Triggered 'refresh' from 2 events
Error: Could not set 'file' on ensure: No such file or directory - /data/puppet-wso2-install-dir/packs/wso2am-2.1.0.zip20170714-16299-1se1com.lock at 95:/etc/puppet/environments/production/modules/wso2base/manifests/install.pp
Error: Could not set 'file' on ensure: No such file or directory - /data/puppet-wso2-install-dir/packs/wso2am-2.1.0.zip20170714-16299-1se1com.lock at 95:/etc/puppet/environments/production/modules/wso2base/manifests/install.pp
Wrapped exception:
No such file or directory - /data/puppet-wso2-install-dir/packs/wso2am-2.1.0.zip20170714-16299-1se1com.lock
Error: /Stage[main]/Wso2am_runtime/Wso2base::Install/File[/data/puppet-wso2-install-dir/packs/wso2am-2.1.0.zip]/ensure: change from absent to file failed: Could not set 'file' on ensure: No such file or directory - /data/puppet-wso2-install-dir/packs/wso2am-2.1.0.zip20170714-16299-1se1com.lock at 95:/etc/puppet/environments/production/modules/wso2base/manifests/install.pp
Notice: /Stage[main]/Wso2am_runtime/Wso2base::Install/Exec[extract_/data/puppet-wso2-install-dir/packs/wso2am-2.1.0.zip]: Dependency File[/data/puppet-wso2-install-dir/packs/wso2am-2.1.0.zip] has failures: true
Warning: /Stage[main]/Wso2am_runtime/Wso2base::Install/Exec[extract_/data/puppet-wso2-install-dir/packs/wso2am-2.1.0.zip]: Skipping because of failed dependencies
Notice: /Stage[main]/Wso2am_runtime/Wso2base::Install/Exec[set_ownership_/data/puppet-wso2-install-dir/wso2am-2.1.0]: Dependency File[/data/puppet-wso2-install-dir/packs/wso2am-2.1.0.zip] has failures: true
Warning: /Stage[main]/Wso2am_runtime/Wso2base::Install/Exec[set_ownership_/data/puppet-wso2-install-dir/wso2am-2.1.0]: Skipping because of failed dependencies
Notice: /Stage[main]/Wso2am_runtime/Wso2base::Install/Exec[set_permissions_/data/puppet-wso2-install-dir/wso2am-2.1.0]: Dependency File[/data/puppet-wso2-install-dir/packs/wso2am-2.1.0.zip] has failures: true
Warning: /Stage[main]/Wso2am_runtime/Wso2base::Install/Exec[set_permissions_/data/puppet-wso2-install-dir/wso2am-2.1.0]: Skipping because of failed dependencies
Notice: /Stage[main]/Wso2am_runtime/Wso2base::Configure/Wso2base::Push_templates[repository/conf/tomcat/catalina-server.xml]/File[/data/puppet-wso2-install-dir/wso2am-2.1.0/repository/conf/tomcat/catalina-server.xml]: Dependency File[/data/puppet-wso2-install-dir/packs/wso2am-2.1.0.zip] has failures: true
Warning: /Stage[main]/Wso2am_runtime/Wso2base::Configure/Wso2base::Push_templates[repository/conf/tomcat/catalina-server.xml]/File[/data/puppet-wso2-install-dir/wso2am-2.1.0/repository/conf/tomcat/catalina-server.xml]: Skipping because of failed dependencies
Notice: /Stage[main]/Wso2am_runtime/Wso2base::Configure/Wso2base::Push_templates[bin/wso2server.sh]/File[/data/puppet-wso2-install-dir/wso2am-2.1.0/bin/wso2server.sh]: Dependency File[/data/puppet-wso2-install-dir/packs/wso2am-2.1.0.zip] has failures: true
Warning: /Stage[main]/Wso2am_runtime/Wso2base::Configure/Wso2base::Push_templates[bin/wso2server.sh]/File[/data/puppet-wso2-install-dir/wso2am-2.1.0/bin/wso2server.sh]: Skipping because of failed dependencies
Notice: /Stage[main]/Wso2am_runtime/Wso2base::Configure/Wso2base::Push_templates[repository/conf/registry.xml]/File[/data/puppet-wso2-install-dir/wso2am-2.1.0/repository/conf/registry.xml]: Dependency File[/data/puppet-wso2-install-dir/packs/wso2am-2.1.0.zip] has failures: true
Warning: /Stage[main]/Wso2am_runtime/Wso2base::Configure/Wso2base::Push_templates[repository/conf/registry.xml]/File[/data/puppet-wso2-install-dir/wso2am-2.1.0/repository/conf/registry.xml]: Skipping because of failed dependencies
Notice: /Stage[main]/Wso2am_runtime/Wso2base::Configure/Wso2base::Push_templates[repository/conf/identity/identity.xml]/File[/data/puppet-wso2-install-dir/wso2am-2.1.0/repository/conf/identity/identity.xml]: Dependency File[/data/puppet-wso2-install-dir/packs/wso2am-2.1.0.zip] has failures: true
Warning: /Stage[main]/Wso2am_runtime/Wso2base::Configure/Wso2base::Push_templates[repository/conf/identity/identity.xml]/File[/data/puppet-wso2-install-dir/wso2am-2.1.0/repository/conf/identity/identity.xml]: Skipping because of failed dependencies
Notice: /Stage[main]/Wso2am_runtime/Wso2base::Configure/Wso2base::Push_templates[repository/conf/api-manager.xml]/File[/data/puppet-wso2-install-dir/wso2am-2.1.0/repository/conf/api-manager.xml]: Dependency File[/data/puppet-wso2-install-dir/packs/wso2am-2.1.0.zip] has failures: true
Warning: /Stage[main]/Wso2am_runtime/Wso2base::Configure/Wso2base::Push_templates[repository/conf/api-manager.xml]/File[/data/puppet-wso2-install-dir/wso2am-2.1.0/repository/conf/api-manager.xml]: Skipping because of failed dependencies
Notice: /Stage[main]/Wso2am_runtime/Wso2base::Configure/Wso2base::Push_templates[repository/conf/identity/application-authentication.xml]/File[/data/puppet-wso2-install-dir/wso2am-2.1.0/repository/conf/identity/application-authentication.xml]: Dependency File[/data/puppet-wso2-install-dir/packs/wso2am-2.1.0.zip] has failures: true
Warning: /Stage[main]/Wso2am_runtime/Wso2base::Configure/Wso2base::Push_templates[repository/conf/identity/application-authentication.xml]/File[/data/puppet-wso2-install-dir/wso2am-2.1.0/repository/conf/identity/application-authentication.xml]: Skipping because of failed dependencies
Notice: /Stage[main]/Wso2am_runtime/Wso2base::Configure/File[/data/puppet-wso2-install-dir/wso2am-2.1.0/repository/components/patches]: Dependency File[/data/puppet-wso2-install-dir/packs/wso2am-2.1.0.zip] has failures: true
Warning: /Stage[main]/Wso2am_runtime/Wso2base::Configure/File[/data/puppet-wso2-install-dir/wso2am-2.1.0/repository/components/patches]: Skipping because of failed dependencies
Notice: /Stage[main]/Wso2am_runtime/Wso2base::Configure/File[/data/puppet-wso2-install-dir/wso2am-2.1.0/repository/components/patches/.gitkeep]: Dependency File[/data/puppet-wso2-install-dir/packs/wso2am-2.1.0.zip] has failures: true
Warning: /Stage[main]/Wso2am_runtime/Wso2base::Configure/File[/data/puppet-wso2-install-dir/wso2am-2.1.0/repository/components/patches/.gitkeep]: Skipping because of failed dependencies
Notice: /Stage[main]/Wso2am_runtime/Wso2base::Configure/Wso2base::Push_templates[repository/conf/identity/EndpointConfig.properties]/File[/data/puppet-wso2-install-dir/wso2am-2.1.0/repository/conf/identity/EndpointConfig.properties]: Dependency File[/data/puppet-wso2-install-dir/packs/wso2am-2.1.0.zip] has failures: true
Warning: /Stage[main]/Wso2am_runtime/Wso2base::Configure/Wso2base::Push_templates[repository/conf/identity/EndpointConfig.properties]/File[/data/puppet-wso2-install-dir/wso2am-2.1.0/repository/conf/identity/EndpointConfig.properties]: Skipping because of failed dependencies
Notice: /Stage[main]/Wso2am_runtime/Wso2base::Configure/Wso2base::Push_templates[repository/conf/datasources/am-datasources.xml]/File[/data/puppet-wso2-install-dir/wso2am-2.1.0/repository/conf/datasources/am-datasources.xml]: Dependency File[/data/puppet-wso2-install-dir/packs/wso2am-2.1.0.zip] has failures: true
Warning: /Stage[main]/Wso2am_runtime/Wso2base::Configure/Wso2base::Push_templates[repository/conf/datasources/am-datasources.xml]/File[/data/puppet-wso2-install-dir/wso2am-2.1.0/repository/conf/datasources/am-datasources.xml]: Skipping because of failed dependencies
Notice: /Stage[main]/Wso2am_runtime/Wso2base::Configure/Wso2base::Push_templates[repository/conf/user-mgt.xml]/File[/data/puppet-wso2-install-dir/wso2am-2.1.0/repository/conf/user-mgt.xml]: Dependency File[/data/puppet-wso2-install-dir/packs/wso2am-2.1.0.zip] has failures: true
Warning: /Stage[main]/Wso2am_runtime/Wso2base::Configure/Wso2base::Push_templates[repository/conf/user-mgt.xml]/File[/data/puppet-wso2-install-dir/wso2am-2.1.0/repository/conf/user-mgt.xml]: Skipping because of failed dependencies
Notice: /Stage[main]/Wso2am_runtime/Wso2base::Configure/Wso2base::Push_templates[repository/conf/security/authenticators.xml]/File[/data/puppet-wso2-install-dir/wso2am-2.1.0/repository/conf/security/authenticators.xml]: Dependency File[/data/puppet-wso2-install-dir/packs/wso2am-2.1.0.zip] has failures: true
Warning: /Stage[main]/Wso2am_runtime/Wso2base::Configure/Wso2base::Push_templates[repository/conf/security/authenticators.xml]/File[/data/puppet-wso2-install-dir/wso2am-2.1.0/repository/conf/security/authenticators.xml]: Skipping because of failed dependencies
Notice: /Stage[main]/Wso2am_runtime/Wso2base::Configure/Wso2base::Push_templates[repository/conf/axis2/axis2.xml]/File[/data/puppet-wso2-install-dir/wso2am-2.1.0/repository/conf/axis2/axis2.xml]: Dependency File[/data/puppet-wso2-install-dir/packs/wso2am-2.1.0.zip] has failures: true
Warning: /Stage[main]/Wso2am_runtime/Wso2base::Configure/Wso2base::Push_templates[repository/conf/axis2/axis2.xml]/File[/data/puppet-wso2-install-dir/wso2am-2.1.0/repository/conf/axis2/axis2.xml]: Skipping because of failed dependencies
Notice: /Stage[main]/Wso2am_runtime/Wso2base::Configure/Wso2base::Push_templates[repository/conf/datasources/master-datasources.xml]/File[/data/puppet-wso2-install-dir/wso2am-2.1.0/repository/conf/datasources/master-datasources.xml]: Dependency File[/data/puppet-wso2-install-dir/packs/wso2am-2.1.0.zip] has failures: true
Warning: /Stage[main]/Wso2am_runtime/Wso2base::Configure/Wso2base::Push_templates[repository/conf/datasources/master-datasources.xml]/File[/data/puppet-wso2-install-dir/wso2am-2.1.0/repository/conf/datasources/master-datasources.xml]: Skipping because of failed dependencies
Notice: /Stage[main]/Wso2am_runtime/Wso2base::Service/Service[wso2am]: Dependency File[/data/puppet-wso2-install-dir/packs/wso2am-2.1.0.zip] has failures: true
Warning: /Stage[main]/Wso2am_runtime/Wso2base::Service/Service[wso2am]: Skipping because of failed dependencies
Notice: /Stage[main]/Wso2am_runtime/Wso2base::Service/Notify[Successfully started WSO2 service [name] wso2am, [CARBON_HOME] /data/puppet-wso2-install-dir/wso2am-2.1.0]: Dependency File[/data/puppet-wso2-install-dir/packs/wso2am-2.1.0.zip] has failures: true
Warning: /Stage[main]/Wso2am_runtime/Wso2base::Service/Notify[Successfully started WSO2 service [name] wso2am, [CARBON_HOME] /data/puppet-wso2-install-dir/wso2am-2.1.0]: Skipping because of failed dependencies
```

Comment: Have you changed the wso2am zip file name?

Comment: yes, i made WUM wso2am-2.1.0.1493283858466.zip to wso2am-2.1.0.zip

Comment: please note: If i Install for the first time with freshly downloaded wso2am-2.1.0.zip from wso2 site it works fine .
The problem occurs only when i take WUM update file then try to update to agents

Comment: The agent claims it cannot read the file **File[/data/puppet-wso2-install-dir/packs/wso2am-2.1.0.zip]/ensure: change from absent to file failed: Could not set 'file' on ensure: No such file or directory**  does the file REALY exists in the source location with right permissions?

Comment: yes, just now i noticed when i start ./setup.sh file /data/puppet-wso2-install-dir/ is empty .
Looks like it is getting deleted when we start ./setup.sh

Comment: looks like ./setup.sh command is deleting the existing files and then trying to install the new one, where as i want to update the existing setup on agent ,  
any help ?